# Server implementation differences between a login request and a create new account request

Tags: security, authentication

I am creating the backend for a system and noticing that the login and create new account requests are virtually identical (I.e. they both contain a username and password) - is there any reason that they should be seperate requests? should the server implement any differences between the requests?

I am seeing something like this:

login:
search for username X,
check that password Y matches saved password,
have user connect

new account:
search for username X,
create username X with password Y,
have user connect

combo:
search for username X,
if X exists, check for password match,
else X does not exist, create X and set password Y,
have user connect

On the client side for a new account they would be asked to enter the password twice (to check for typo's/etc.) and asked to read the TOS/etc. of course

are there any security concerns with doing something like this? how is this normally handled?

Comment: Its okay, if you handle the user data the right way - anyways, the common method is to have registration and login seperated because its more user-friendly (in my opinion).

Comment: Usually more info is required for account creation, f.e. an email address, and maybe additional data. But no one’s stopping you from handling this in the same code branch if you want to … that’s up to you. But you should be able to distinguish both types of request server-side – and not _create_ a new account f.e. when a user simply mis-types their user name.

Comment: @CBroe - I am not understanding why the server would need to distinquish between the two requests in order to prevent the creation of an account when the user mis-types their name, as they would have used a different client page, entered their password twice, etc. before the request would have been sent from the client

Comment: That’s because you’re assuming that you control what’s going on client-side – which of course you don’t. You’re wrong already when you assume, any request reaching your server would have to come from something called a “browser”.